# Button in front of div

Tags: css, position, overlay

I'm not a CSS expert. I'm trying to place an `<input type="button">` in the center of an `<img>` and I'm having some trouble doing so. [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a6tA7/) and here is my HTML:

```html
<div id="avatar">
    <img src="http://www.averageadjustersusca.org/aaa/images/profileholder.gif" alt="My avatar" />
    <input id="btnAvatar" class="button" type="button" name="Button" value="Change">
    <p>Text</p>
</div>
```

I want the input to be displayed over the image, also, the text need to be at the right. I tried using:

```css
img { width: 300px; height: 300px; float: left; }
input { position: absolute; margin:140px 0px 0px 130px;}
```

But it only works on chrome / safari, on other browsers, the button is placed after the image and not in front of it.

What is the best way to do this?

<sub>Obs.: The space where the button is, needs to be empty, or else, the text will move up.</sub>

---

This is how it's displayed on chrome:

[image]

This is how it's displayed on firefox:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify the x and y positions on an absolute position. Change the css for input to this:

```
input { position: absolute; top:0; left:0; margin:140px 0px 0px 130px;}
```

Comment: I see, so I think chrome / safari assumes 0 as default top and left. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

There is a simple and clean method for doing this code. The trick is to use the DIV tag to contain and position everything in place.

1. Use a main DIV to contain everything and give it the position:relative property.
2. Place the img and input tags in a single DIV and assign this DIV the float:left property.
3. Using CSS to select the P tag and float it to the left. This will position the text beside the DIV containing the img and input.
4. Now assign the input tag the position:absolute property while using the properties TOP & LEFT to postion it into place.

Here's an example:

```
<div id="avatar-container">
     <div id="avatar-image-btn">
          <img src="http://www.averageadjustersusca.org/aaa/images/profileholder.gif" alt="My avatar"  />
          <input id="btnAvatar" class="button" type="button" name="Button" value="Change">
     </div>
     <p>Text</p>
</div>

<style> 
    #avatar-container { position: relative; }
    #avatar-container p { float: left; }
    #avatar-image-btn { float: left; }
    #avatar-image-btn img { }
    #avatar-image-btn input { position: absolute; top: 135px; left: 120px; cursor: pointer; }
</style>
```

See, clean and simple, works every time and is multi-browser compatible.

*The margin property can cause a mess when used without caution. Best practice is to use it for stacking tags in divs and not for positioning with large gapping margins.

Answer (score 2):

use z-index

```
input { position: absolute; margin:140px 0px 0px 130px; z-index:2}
```

this is pushing your button one layer up

after understanding the question correctly here is a solution

```
img { width: 300px; height: 300px; float: left; border:1px solid black; position:absolute}
input { position: absolute; margin:140px 0px 0px 130px;}
```

as mentioned bellow in comments the problem was in positioning

Comment: The problem is not the index of the input, it's where the button is located. On chrome, it appears right, but on firefox, it's placed after the image.

Comment: I got your solution :)) the img you have is positioned relative cause you don't specify the position option and default is relative that's the problem you are facing and this is your solution 
`img { width: 300px; height: 300px; float: left; border:1px solid black; position:absolute}
input { position: absolute; margin:140px 0px 0px 130px;}`

Comment: Having the image set to `position:absolute` causes the text to overlap/underlap the image. I recommend changing this to `position:relative`

Answer (score 1):

You may add `position:relative` for #avatar and give #btnAvatar `top:0; left:0;`

Answer (score 1):

This should do it: http://jsfiddle.net/a6tA7/9/

I would recommend you use `top:` and `left:` to position the input element rather than `margin:`